# How to debug C++ code on VSCode? MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code, include-path

I have downloaded the C++ extension and this is my launch.json file.
[image]

What should I need to do to debug it? I keep having this error.
[image]

Is it possible to debug C++ code on MacOS? Anything I should add/download/create first?

**Update :**
Here is what I did base on answers below and I get this
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use *cppvsdbg* as the debugger, unless you are using the Visual Studio Windows debugger. For Mac OS X you should be using *cppdbg* as the debugger *type*.

Besides that, your *program* entry points to a directory, not an executable image. Change that to something like `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out"`. As [documented](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md), this entry *"[s]pecifies the full path to executable the debugger will launch or attach to."*

More information available at [Configuring launch.json for C/C++ debugging](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Check out the update I made above. Still not sure what is missing.

Comment: @Student: Your `"program"` setting (at least for the *C++ Attach* configuration) is wrong (*"Specifies the full path to executable the debugger will launch or attach to."*). It should point to the **executable** that is the result of compiling and linking the source and object code. It is called *a.out* by default.